# split json array response for each input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry for the repost I just need it badly and it's important!
I have other posts with the same but I flagged the question answered and I have still not figure out how to fix!

I have this ajax response :

```
[{"error":"uname","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05dd \u05de\u05e9\u05ea\u05de\u05e9 \u05d0\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5 \u05d9\u05db."},{"error":"email","message":"&nbsp;\u05d0\u05e0\u05d0 \u05d4\u05db\u05e0\u05e1 \u05d0\u05d9\u05de\u05d9\u05dc"},{"error":"password","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05d3\u05d4 \u05d6\u05d47"},{"error":"oldpassinp","message":"&nbsp;\u05d4\u05e7\u05e9 \u05e1\u05d9\u05e1\u05de\u05d0 \u05e9\u05dc."}]
```

and my input fields like this :

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" class="inplaceError"/><span id="fname_error"></span>
```

the span holds the message errors.

I use this in client side :

```
 var data_array = JSON.parse("["+data+"]");
 // tryed either var data_array = JSON.parse(data); not working too

  for (var i in data_array )
  {
     $("#"+data_array[i].error+"_error").html(data_array[i].message);
     $("#"+data_array[i].error).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
  }
```

what wrong with that code ? It's not adding the errors for each field please any help.

I am javascript newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ajax request is of datatype: 'json' then the response will a json array

```
$.each(data, function(idx, error){
    $("#"+error.error+"_error").html(error.message);
})
```

Comment: OMG UR KING! its working! thanks u so much! i will flag ur answer in 9 minute cuz the system not let me yet.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` is only used when you are receiving a string of JSON that needs to be converted to a JSON object.  In your example, you are providing a JSON object.  If you are receiving JSON in your ajax request's response, then no parsing is needed.

If this is the case, then you also don't need to wrap your data in brackets, especially with string concatenation.

in this case, you can just iterate over the JSON object itself, like so:

```
for(var i in data) {
    $("#"+ data[i].error+"_error").html(data[i].message);
    $("#"+ data[i].error).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
}
```

Also, it looks like your JSON example data does not have a `fname` key, which may be contributing to your frustrations (I only saw `uname`).

As mentioned below, you can also just use jQuery's each method for iterating, but a for loop will suffice.

I hope that helps.